# list requires class type

Tags: c++, class, sorting

So I'm trying to make a bubble sort algorithm in class and I'm having this problem where it keeps giving me an error when I'm trying to find the length of the list where it says "expression must have a class type" and for the life of me I cannot figure out what to do. the tutorial I'm using isn't an help and I cannot find any other people with the same problem.

if anyone gets what it is asking I would appreciate the help, and any explanation would also be appreciated  as I'm still new and would like to understand so I can try to learn
this was all done on VS 2017 (the free version)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
 {
    bool found = true;
    int target{ 0 };
    int temp{};
    bool ordered{ false };

    int list[10] = { 4,6,5,1,3,2,10,8,9,7 };    
    cout << list.length() << endl;


    bool swapped{ false };

    while (ordered = false)
    {
        target = 0;
        while (target != list.length)
        {
            if (list[target] > list[target + 1])
            {
                swapped == true;
                list[target] = temp;
                list[target] = list[target + 1];
                list[target + 1] = temp;
                target = target + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                target = target + 1;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false)
        {
            ordered = true;
        }
    }
    cout << list << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[link to the photo of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ9I7.png)

Comment: Tutorials are rubbish. Get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "`while (ordered = false)`" -- even if you get this to compile, your program will, unfortunately, not do anything useful. This won't work. "`swapped == true;`" and this won't work either. There are multiple, fundamental bugs in the shown code. Time for you to get a good C++ book, and work through it slowly, one chapter at a time. C++ does not, I repeat, does not have a reputation for instant gratification. Learning to write correct C++ code takes a long time.

Comment: Just use a standard container, like `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have mentioned ("expression must have a class type") is caused by the below statement and other similar statements :

```
cout << list.length() << endl;
```

`list` is an integer array of size 10 as per this statement `int list[10];`

So you cannot use a `.` on it. You can use the `.` operator on a structure or class or union only. And even if `list` were a class/structure, `length()` method should be defined in it for the above to work.

Instead you should use `sizeof` operator. You can store it in a variable and use it later on.

```
size_t length = sizeof list/sizeof list[0]; 
cout << length << endl;
```